# Sublime snippet with a trigger other than tab

Tags: sublimetext2, sublimetext3, sublimetext

Is it possible to create a Sublime Text snippet with a trigger that doesn't use the tab key?

For example, if I want a comment block, could I type:  `/comblock` and then hit Enter instead of tab?

Comment: You could use a sublime completion, and set your preferences to use space to complete

Comment: @RyanB Thanks, but wouldn't changing my completion preference to space change it for everything? I still want tab functionality too.

Comment: Then I don't think so off hand, maybe a plug-in?